# Kendo Ui TabStrip left and right button disable instant of hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I want to disable the left and right arrow key once reach the first li list and last li list.
Right now once I reach on last ul li list the right arrow is hidden but I want to disable the arrow instant of hiding because it shows space.

I added if statement but its not working

Demo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@vishal14/UcaPEYoh

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with your selector. Try the jQuery selector like this:

```
if($('.k-button:visible').length > 0){
     $(this).css("opacity","0.2");    
} else{
     $(this).css("opacity","1");
}
```